# How to disable viewing Window's hidden files in Ubuntu?

Tags: filemanager

I used Ubuntu 10.10 with Wubi. It has been such a confusing matter that my hidden files on Window now can easily be seen on Ubuntu. It's not good at all.

How can I disable this function of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your using Nautilus File Manager you can create a file called '.hidden' in the directory where you want to hide files, open it with a text editor, and add the names of the files you want to hide (with each files respective extension as well).

This is not an system wide automatic method of hiding files without renaming it (in Linux files and folders are automatically hidden if they have "." in front of the file/folder name).  You would have to do this manually for every file/folder that you want to effect; and only feasible for the Windows system files/folders that you really want to keep hidden and not want to mess around.

Comment: It would be possible to write a script to automate that task, though, but I don't know of any existing one.

Comment: a fast way to do it at least, is to just select all files to hide in the nautilus, copy them, and paste it into an editor, which will output all the path to the files. it will just take 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Also the fact that you are even concerned about it is alarming because it sounds like you think that hiding a file provides some sort of security.  It does not.  Showing hidden files is easily done in either Ubuntu or Windows, and I never have them NOT shown.

Comment: I don't think he's trying to hide them for security reasons. It sounds to me more like he's just trying to reduce the visual clutter he has to dig through when browsing his Windows folders.