# Hide files and folders which are hidden in Windows

Tags: 11.04, filesystem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable viewing Window's hidden files in Ubuntu ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51202/how-to-disable-viewing-windows-hidden-files-in-ubuntu)

How can I hide files and folder in Ubuntu so files and folders which are hidden in Windows are also hidden in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu and windows use different ways of hiding files. Ubuntu hides all files prepended with a period (eg. '.fubar'), while windows uses a different method. Because of this, I don't think you can easily hide the same files on windows and ubuntu without some kind of renaming script.